# SQL Server equivalent to MySQL UNIQUE index?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, sql-server-express

In MySQL (5.1) I am able to create a Index on a field that is type UNIQUE.  This ensures that the field contains only unique items.

Is there something equivalent to that feature in SQL Server 2008?

An example of MySQL Table CREATE syntax with UNIQUE Index:

```
CREATE TABLE `routelist` (
    `RouteID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `RouteName` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `Active` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`RouteID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `RouteName` (`RouteName`)
)
COMMENT='3.29.2012'
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

Comment: Have you done any searching? SQL-Server [UNIQUE constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx)

Comment: @ypercube Indeed. 2nd hit in Google for "SQL Server UNIQUE Index"

Comment: I was trying to search for SQL server equivalent to MySQL unique index and wasn't getting any good results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's syntax is just a shortcut for a create index.

So in SQL Server use:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX routename ON routelist (routename);
```

works in MySQL just as well.

Comment: MySQL's shortcut is to create both a UNIQUE constraint and a UNIQUE index. You can't create only one of the two.

Comment: In SQL-Server, creating a UNIQUE constraint, creates a UNIQUE index, too. But creating an index does not also create a UNIQUE constraint. Off course the Uniqueness is enforced but I think that FKs cannot reference this column in this case. (Have to test that)

Comment: No, my bad. You can add FK, even with only a Unique index defined: [Unique index and Foreign Key](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65524/unique-index-and-foreign-key)

Answer (score 2):

A note. There is one big difference between `UNIQUE` constraints in SQL-Server and all other DBMS (MySQL included) and the SQL standard, in which a nullable column with a Unique constraint can have multiple Nulls. But in SQL-Server only one Null is allowed:

> Also, unlike PRIMARY KEY constraints, UNIQUE constraints allow for the value NULL. However, as with any value participating in a UNIQUE constraint, ***only one null value is allowed per column.***

Comment: Is there a difference between a unique index and a unique constraint for SQL server (regarding the multiple NULLs)

Comment: I don't think so: [UNIQUE Constraint](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65520/unique-constraint) and [Unique index](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65522/unique-index)

Comment: +1 Good pointer on the difference between SQL server and other RDBMs.